# link inside pdf in new tab Window

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I want to open hyperlink in new tab which is in generated pdf.

```
  <?php if(($appval['name'])== 'PDF'){?>
         <dt ><?php echo stripslashes($appval['name']); ?></dt>
        <dd><a href=<?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?> target="_blank"><?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?></a></dd>
    <?php } else{?>
            <dt ><?php echo stripslashes($appval['name']); ?></dt>
        <dd><?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?></dd>
        <?php }?>
            <?php } ?>
            </dl>
            <hr />
            <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
        <?php  }            
    }  
}
```

This does work :

```
<dd><a href=<?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?> target="_blank"><?php echo stripslashes($appval['value']); ?></a></dd>
```

Comment: You can try this link and follow on: [Open a new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , In my case i got the embedded output file .
html elements are not considering .

Answer (score 0):

In a quick visual walkthrough of your code snippet, separating it out in a text editor to make the conditional branching a little easier to follow, I notice that if control passes into your `else` branch, no `</a>` will be issued. Your `if-true` branch does issue an `</a>`, and the code you have introduced as "This does work:" issues one as well, but the `else` branch does not.